# Why does my window layout change when I change my selection?

Tags: python, qt, layout

If you look at my two images [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DPHxN.jpg), you'll notice that switching between the two selections changes the size of the `QListWidget` on the right.

I have it laid out using a `QGridLayout`. Here is the relevant code snippet, with `pn_list` being the relevant widget, but you can see the full code [here](http://pastebin.com/MHdL8XRH):

```
def initUI(self):
    # Layouts
    grid = QtGui.QGridLayout()
    ov_main = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
    ov_col1 = QtGui.QFormLayout()
    ov_col2 = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
    ov_custs = QtGui.QFormLayout()


    # Main window widgets
    self.pn_input = QtGui.QLineEdit()
    overviewBox = QtGui.QGroupBox('Overview')
    self.pn_list = MyListWidget()

    # Main window layout
    grid.addWidget(QtGui.QLabel('Part Number'), 1, 1)
    grid.addWidget(self.pn_input, 1, 2)
    grid.addWidget(overviewBox, 2, 1, 1, 2)
    grid.addWidget(self.pn_list, 1, 3, 2, 1)
```

Update: Also, as a follow-on question, what can I do to prevent this from happening? Finally, I would like the "Description" field to wrap when the line-length exceeds a pre-determined character limit - I currently have my presenter truncating the "Description" when it exceeds this length. How would I have the `QLabel` wrap at a given character width?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. On the `MyListWidget` (which extends `QListWidget`) I overwrote the `sizeHint` method to return the width, in pixels, that I want my widget to be:

```
class MyListWidget(QtGui.QListWidget):

    def sizeHint(self):
        hint = QtCore.QSize()
        hint.setWidth(120)
        return hint
```

Then, in my `initUI` method, I added a line to the `#Main window layout` section:

```
# Main window layout
grid.addWidget(QtGui.QLabel('Part Number'), 1, 1)
grid.addWidget(self.pn_input, 1, 2)
grid.addWidget(overviewBox, 2, 1, 1, 2)
grid.addWidget(self.pn_list, 1, 3, 2, 1)
```

This kept the widget on the right a constant width, however I still had problems with varying length descriptions messing things up. I added the following lines to my `initUI` method to similarly deal with the description `QLabel` widget and now all is well:

```
myQLabel.sizeHint = lambda: QtCore.QSize(150, -1)
myQLabel.setSizePolicy(QtGui.QSizePolicy.Fixed, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
myQLabel.setWordWrap(True)
```

The lambda statement is essentially a quicker way of achieving what I did with the `QListWidget`. In the `QListWidget` case, I was already re-implementing the class in order to add a custom signal, so I added the `sizeHint` code there.